# Disable link preview on android message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We have a website and when someone will get text message with link to this website, I would like to, as a developer,  disable / hide link preview on Android devices. So only URL address will be visible. I still would like to keep those links previews on IOS devices. Is this possible and how?

I was trying with open graph protocol and with changing meta links, however this is not working:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com" />
<meta property="og:image" 
content="https://something/content/img/blank.png" />
```

I can change image but not disable it completely. I don't want to see this link preview, small thumbnail on android device at all.

Comment: I think you should use javascript for check device or you can use CSS `@media` query for do it but you can't use `@media` query for specifying the android device

Comment: good idea, but if I will find out what type of device they using, for example with javascirpt, I still don't know how to disable this link preview

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/detect-mobile-devices-jquery/) reference there have more example

first you need to create global function for the detect mobile device

```
/**
 * jQuery.browser.mobile (http://detectmobilebrowser.com/)
 * jQuery.browser.mobile will be true if the browser is a mobile device
 **/
(function(a){jQuery.browser.mobile=/android.+mobile|avantgo|bada/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw-(n|u)|c55/|capi|ccwa|cdm-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf-5|g-mo|go(.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd-(m|p|t)|hei-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs-c|ht(c(-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |-|/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |/)|klon|kpt |kwc-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|/(k|l|u)|50|54|e-|e/|-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1-w|m3ga|m50/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt-g|qa-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|-[2-7]|i-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h-|oo|p-)|sdk/|se(c(-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh-|shar|sie(-|m)|sk-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h-|v-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl-|tdg-|tel(i|m)|tim-|t-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m-|m3|m5)|tx-9|up(.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(-|2|g)|yas-|your|zeto|zte-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera)
```

then you can use it like below example

```
if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
{
   console.log('You are using a mobile device!');
}
else
{
   console.log('You are not using a mobile device!');
}
```